# Show the renewal function is differentiable

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, convolution, renewal-processes

***Definition.***

For a sequence of $\text{i.i.d.}$ random variables $ \left\{X_{k},k\ge 1 \right \},$called
inter-renewal times, let $S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k},n\ge 0,$ be the time instant of the $n$th event,
and $N(t)=\text{max} \left\{n: S_n \le t \right\}$ be the total number of replacements occurred by time $t$.Then $\left\{S_n \ge 0 \right\}$ is called a ***renewal process*** and $\left\{N(t),t\le 0 \right\}$ is
called a ***renewal counting process***.

Let the cumulative distribution functions for $S_{n},n\ge 0,$ as follows: $F_{0}(x)=\begin{cases}
 &0 \quad x<0\\
 &1  \quad x\ge0 
\end{cases};F_{1}=F(x);F_{n}(x)=F^{n*}(x),$ for $n\ge 1,$  where $F^{n*}(x)$ is the $n$-fold convolution of $F$ with itself.

Next, we can obtain the mean of $N(t)$, which is called the ***renewal function*** and
denoted by $M(t)=\mathbf{E}[N(t)]$, in terms of $F_n.$
$$M(t)=\mathbf{E}[N(t)]=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}P(N(t)\ge n)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}P(S_{n}\le t)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}F_{n}(t).(\star)$$

For the case where the inter-renewal times $X_{1},X_{2},...$ are  $\text{i.i.d.}$ continuous random variables(a random variable is called continuous iff its CDF is a continuous function). with $\text{p.d.f.} f(x),$ the renewal function is differentiable and  $$m(t)=\frac{\mathrm{d}M(t) }{\mathrm{d} x}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}(t),$$ where $f_{n}(t)$ is $\text{p.d.f.}$ for $S_{n}.$

---

I don't know why the renewal function $M(t)$ is differentiable under $\left\{ X_{n}\right\}_{n\ge 1}$ are continuous random variables with $\text{p.d.f.}$ I think  we should introduce additional conditions that enable the interchange of the summation and differentiation symbols,such as,$$\forall t\ge 0,F(t)<1,
\text{since this implies} $$$$M(t)\le F(t)(1-F(t))^{-1}\text {from } (\star)$$

Comment: It is true almost everywhere. If $g=\sum g_n$ converges and each $g_n$ is increasing then $g'=\sum g_n'$ almost everywhere.

Comment: @geetha290krm:What if we require it to hold everywhere? What about Dini'theorem? But applying  Dini'theorem to interchange of the summation and differentiation we need some additional conditions.

Comment: pdf's are only defined a.e. So you need strong conditions on $F_n$ to make the equation hold for every $t$.

Comment: @geetha290krm: Let $f(t)$, the$\text{ p.d.f.}$ for $\text{i.i.d.}\left\{X_n\right\} n\ge 1,$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and  $\displaystyle \lim_{ t\to \infty}f(t)=A\in\mathbb{R}, \lim_{ t\to -\infty}f(t)=B\in\mathbb{R}$.
I think that could be a strong condition on $F_{n}(t):=F^{n*}(t)$ making the equation holds for every $t$.

Comment: @geetha290krm:Since $f(t)$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. For each fixed $t_{0}\in \mathbb{R}$,
taking $\delta>0$ such that $|f(t) - f(t_{0})|<\epsilon$ whenever $|t-t_0|<\delta$.Then if $|t-t_0| < \delta$, 
$$|f*f(t) - f*f(t_0)| \le \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(u)| |f(u-t) - f(u-t_0)|\ du \le \epsilon \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(u)|du= \epsilon.$$ By induction, it can be seen that $f_{n}(t)$,the $\text{p.d.f.}$of $S_{n}=\sum^{n}_{k=1}X_k$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$,such as the convolution of $\text{i.i.d.  }\text{Normal}(\mu,\sigma).$

Answer (score 1):

When the $X_k$s have a density $f$, so that each $S_n$ has density $f_n$, then $F_n(t) =\int_0^t f_n(u)\,du$ for each $t\ge0$ and each $n\ge 1$. Therefore
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty F_n(t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^t f_n(u)\,du=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^t f_n(u)\,du=\int_0^t\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(u)\right)\,du,
$$
the exchange of summation and integration being justified by Tonelli's Theorem.
Defining $m(u):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(u)$, this shows that
$$
M(t) =\int_0^t m(u)\,du
$$
for all $t\ge 0$. The Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem implies that $M'(t) =m(t)$ for a.e. $t\ge 0$.